# How to make NASM generate short jump by default?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I have a disassembly of a 16-bit DOS COM file, which I want to assemble to a close as possible binary.

I'm using NASM, but in spite of the manual saying that jumps in general are encoded as short by default, they're actually encoded as near when using numeric addresses.

Procedure (file contents in section below):

```
nasm jumps_short.asm -fbin -o jumps_short.com
nasm jumps_unspecified.asm -fbin -o jumps_unspecified.com
ndisasm -o 04FEH jumps_short.com > jumps_short.dis.asm
ndisasm -o 04FEH jumps_unspecified.com > jumps_unspecified.dis.asm
```

`jumps_unspecified.asm`:

```
bits 16
org 04FEh
main:
    JNZ  0x0529
    TEST BYTE [SI+0x0431], 0x02
    JNZ  0x050A
```

`jumps_short.asm`:

```
bits 16
org 04FEh
main:
    JNZ  SHORT 0x0529
    TEST BYTE [SI+0x0431], 0x02
    JNZ  SHORT 0x050A
```

`jumps_unspecified.dis.asm`:

```
000004FE  0F852700          jnz word 0x529
00000502  F684310402        test byte [si+0x431],0x2
00000507  0F85FFFF          jnz word 0x50a
```

`jumps_short.dis.asm`:

```
000004FE  7529              jnz 0x529
00000500  F684310402        test byte [si+0x431],0x2
00000505  7503              jnz 0x50a
```

Comment: NASM may be assembling 16-bit relative near jumps because the destinations are out of range of a 8-bit relative short jump. If that's the actual complete code you're assembling then the `.04FE  JNZ  0x0529` instruction will be at address 0, and so be 0x0529 bytes away the branch destination.

Comment: You do realize the `.04FE` just a label and won't make nasm place the code at the right location?

Comment: You are interpreting that incorrectly.  They are absolutely being assembled as short jumps.  Notice that `JNZ 0x0529` takes only 2 bytes.  That would be the short jump instruction followed by the +- short offset.  A near jump would have been encoded to include the longer near destination.  Your disassembly is simply showing you what the offset is that the jump continues at.  Try using an objdump and reading the hex output to prove this to yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware that labels won't affect the address; they were present only because the code was coming from a modified DOS DEBUG dump. I've removed them, since they were obviously confusing.

Comment: Hello everybody! I've provided processable examples, with the results.

Comment: Can't it be, that your problem is arising from using the immediate value instead of label? If you rewrite `jnz 0x0529` to `jnz label_0529` and add `label_0529:` at appropriate place in the code, does the "unspecified" variant produce proper code?

Comment: If I use labels, it does generate short jumps (I'll add it to the description), still, such inconsistency is puzzling to me.